# spring JPA to post in API request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, http-headers

Here im trying to fetch the data row by row from mysql db with findby function and it worked fine, but the next step I'm trying to access an API to fill the needed data from my table to API throught http `POST` and change the `processDate` to current date , but im getting an error when i try to implement the `commandlineruner`

error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner,
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: null

The API format looks like :

```
{
  "ChannelID":"113", # static string no change on it
  "MSISDN":"XXX", # i have to fill it wil my msisdn 
  "ServiceID":"XXX" i have to fill it with my param1
}
```

AccessingDataJpaApplication class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    @Autowired

    private Bulk_repositoryRepository bulk_repositoryRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }
    Date currentDate = new Date();

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
         RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
         headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
         headers.setBasicAuth("######", "#####");

         while(true) {

            for (Bulk_repository churnss : bulk_repositoryRepository.findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateLessThanAndCampEndDateGreaterThanEqual(0,54,currentDate,currentDate)) {
                logger.info(churnss.toString());
                AddOfferRequest AddOffer = new AddOfferRequest("113", churnss.getMsisdn(),churnss.getParam1());

                logger.info(AddOffer.toString());
                HttpEntity<AddOfferRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<AddOfferRequest>(AddOffer,headers);

                ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                "API LINK.......", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

                if(responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK){
                    String response = responseEntity.getBody();
                    logger.info(response);

                    churnss.setStatus(1);
                    churnss.setProcessDate(new Date());
                    logger.info(churnss.toString());
                    bulk_repositoryRepository.save(churnss);
                }
            }
            wait(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

AddOfferRequest class :

```
public class AddOfferRequest {

    private String ChannelID="113";
    private String MSISDN;
    private String ServiceID;

    public AddOfferRequest() {
    }
    public AddOfferRequest(String channelID,String mSISDN,String serviceID ) {
        this.MSISDN = mSISDN;
        this.ServiceID = serviceID;

    }

    public void setMSISDN(String mSISDN) {
        this.MSISDN = mSISDN;
    }

    public void setServiceID(String serviceID) {
        this.ServiceID = serviceID;
    }

    public String getChannelID() {
        return ChannelID;
    }

    public String getMSISDN() {
        return MSISDN;
    }

    public String getServiceID() {
        return ServiceID;
    }

}
```

Bulk_repository class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BULK_REPOSITORY")
public class Bulk_repository {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "msisdn")
   private String msisdn;

   @Column(name = "camp_start_date")   
   private Date campStartDate;

   @Column(name = "camp_end_date")
   private Date campEndDate;

   @Column(name = "camp_type")
   private int campType;

   @Column(name = "camp_cd")
   private String camp_cd;

   @Column(name = "status")
   private int status;

   @Column(name = "process_date")
   private Date processDate;

   @Column(name = "entry_date")
   private Date entryDate;

   @Column(name = "entry_user")
   private String entry_user;

   @Column(name = "param1")
   private String param1;

   @Column(name = "param2")
   private String param2;

   @Column(name = "param3")
   private String param3;

   @Column(name = "param4")
   private String param4;

   @Column(name = "param5")
   private String param5;

   @Column(name = "error_desc")
   private String error_desc;

   @Column(name = "fulfilment_status")
   private int fulfilment_status;
## then getter and setters and to tostring
```

Bulk_repositoryRepository class :

```
public interface Bulk_repositoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Bulk_repository, Long> {
      List<Bulk_repository>findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateLessThanAndCampEndDateGreaterThanEqual(int status, int campType,Date currentDate, Date currentDate1);

      Bulk_repository findById(long id);
}
```

stacktrace :

```
2019-10-26 17:25:47.563  INFO 10275 --- [           main] c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : Starting AccessingDataJpaApplication on ubuntu with PID 10275 (/home/devops/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/gs-accessing-data-jpa-complete/target/classes started by devops in /home/devops/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/gs-accessing-data-jpa-complete)
2019-10-26 17:25:47.572  INFO 10275 --- [           main] c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-26 17:25:50.970  INFO 10275 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-26 17:25:51.141  INFO 10275 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 149ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-10-26 17:25:51.948  INFO 10275 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58bd9157] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-10-26 17:25:52.578  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-26 17:25:52.693  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-26 17:25:52.711  INFO 10275 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-10-26 17:25:53.002  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-26 17:25:53.003  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5219 ms
2019-10-26 17:25:53.389  INFO 10275 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-10-26 17:25:53.790  INFO 10275 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-10-26 17:25:53.891  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-10-26 17:25:54.339  INFO 10275 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-10-26 17:25:54.342  INFO 10275 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-10-26 17:25:54.755  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-10-26 17:25:55.225  INFO 10275 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-10-26 17:25:56.861  INFO 10275 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-26 17:25:54.214  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-10-26 17:25:54.299  WARN 10275 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-10-26 17:25:54.798  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-10-26 17:25:54.804  INFO 10275 --- [           main] c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : Started AccessingDataJpaApplication in 9.283 seconds (JVM running for 16.131)
2019-10-26 17:25:54.908  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-10-26 17:25:55.220  INFO 10275 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-26 17:25:55.236 ERROR 10275 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:783) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.accessingdatajpa.AccessingDataJpaApplication.main(AccessingDataJpaApplication.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.accessingdatajpa.AccessingDataJpaApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.java:71) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2019-10-26 17:25:55.269  INFO 10275 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-10-26 17:25:55.270  INFO 10275 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-26 17:25:55.278  INFO 10275 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-10-26 17:25:55.298  INFO 10275 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace that I can see where the problem happens?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i have update my question with stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in a synchronized block in order for Object.wait() to work. It is used in multi-threaded environment for synchronizing your threads. But I assume you simply want your code to wait a bit between logging the latest results.

Use `Thread.sleep(1000)` instead.